# How to Get Connected Component with Graphframes in Pyspark and Raw Data in Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx, graphframes

I have a spark data frame which looks like below:

```
+--+-----+---------+
|id|phone|  address|
+--+-----+---------+
| 0|  123| james st|
| 1|  177|avenue st|
| 2|  123|spring st|
| 3|  999|avenue st|
| 4|  678|  5th ave|
+--+-----+---------+
```

I am trying to use `graphframes` package to identify the connected component of **ids** using **phone** and **address** from above spark data frame. So this data frame can be treated as **vertices** data frame of the graph.

I am wondering what would be the optimal approach creating the **edges** data frame of the graph to feed into the `connectedComponents()` function in `graphframes`?

Ideally, the `edges` data frame should look like below:

```
+---+---+------------+
|src|dst|relationship|
+---+---+------------+
| 0 |  2|  same_phone|
| 1 |  3|same_address|
+---+---+------------+
```

Finally, the `connectedComponents()` results should be like below. **id** **0 & 1** are in the same component based on the **same_phone** relationship and **1 & 3** based on the **same_address** relationship. Then, this would leave **4** as another component which has no connection with other **ids**.

```
+---+-------------------+
|id |connected_component|
+---+-------------------+
|0  |1                  |
|1  |2                  |
|2  |1                  |
|3  |2                  |
|4  |3                  |
+---+-------------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if there is one more row with id=`5`, phone=`123` and address=`avenue st`, what would be the desired `connected_component`?

Comment: here's a nice example of explaining how to find connected components of the graph : https://towardsdatascience.com/graphframes-in-jupyter-a-practical-guide-9b3b346cebc5

Comment: Hi @jxc, in that case, id (0, 1, 2, 3, 5) would be in the same component. It leaves id 4 in a separated component.

Comment: @user238607. Yes this is a good reference. I looked into it and a few other ones. They are all creating edge list by manually creating an edge data frame. However, this won't work in my case as my vertices data have a few million records.

Comment: The connected component IDs are totally unrelated to the edge IDs. They start from 0 and count up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce

edges = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x.union(y),
    [df.alias('t1')
       .join(df.alias('t2'), c)
       .filter('t1.id < t2.id')
       .selectExpr('t1.id src', 't2.id dst', "'same_%s' relationship"% c) for c in df.columns[1:]
    ]
)

edges.show()
+---+---+------------+
|src|dst|relationship|
+---+---+------------+
|  0|  2|  same_phone|
|  1|  3|same_address|
+---+---+------------+
```

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

connect = edges.select(
    F.array_sort(F.array('src', 'dst')).alias('arr')
).distinct().union(
    df.join(edges, (df.id == edges.src) | (df.id == edges.dst), 'anti').select(F.array('id'))
).withColumn(
    'connected_component', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('arr'))
).select(F.explode('arr').alias('id'), 'connected_component')

connect.show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|connected_component|
+---+-------------------+
|  0|                  1|
|  2|                  1|
|  1|                  2|
|  3|                  2|
|  4|                  3|
+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: this one requires graphframe.connectedComponents as the OP mentioned, from his another post, it should be an easy fix now for this task.

Comment: Thank you both for answering my questions. Both this and the self join solutions we discussed in another post work for my task!